# How to color a row in table depending on time?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am creating an application that will help our employees manage tasks. Tasks are submited via form. OnBeforeCreate I'm taking a date of task subbmission:

`record.Data_Zlozenia = new Date();`

The task falls into view for region (table widget), from where employees can pick it up.

The task that is submmited has 48 hour deadline.

Problem: **How to color the row of task that exceed the deadline?**

I know that I can color the row via adding a class in style editor and then on the row "Display" styles the binding. But I don't know how to make it depend on time.

```
`.red {
  background-color: red;
}

 @widget.descendants.Field3.text === "Oczekujący - zwrot" ? ['red','app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor'] : ['app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor']`
```

EDIT 1: Here I give U screenshots how it looks and what I tried. 
[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi9Vh.png)
[Bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYHxV.png)

EDIT 2: With @Markus help I found a solution. I should put a binding like this:

```
(@datasource.item.Data_Zlozenia)/3600000 < ((new Date())/3600000 - 48) ? ['red','app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor'] : ['app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but I would try the following in your row styles binding:

```
setInterval(function() {(new Date() - @widget.datasource.item.Data_Zlozenia)/3600000;}, 60000) > 48 ? ['red','app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor'] : ['app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor']
```

Hypothetically speaking this will take the current Date/Time minus your field Date/Time and convert it to hours by dividing it by 3.6 million (JS date minus a date will return milliseconds so you have to convert to hours) and it will repeat this function every minute (60000 milliseconds). As stated, this is untested so you might need to refine a little

Comment: I have tried what You suggested, but it dosen't work, moreover any error has arisen. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. In the Edit section in my post, I put some screenshoots to give U more information about my project.

Comment: I put some log on this function to see what it returns. This is the log: 

**console.log((new Date() - @widget.datasource.item.Data_Zlozenia))/3600000)**

And this is what it returns: **GMT+200 2019
169.07026194444444**

Comment: I think I found a solution. I have put it in the Edit2 section in my post.